# A Variable from a module will not be exported

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell Modul: SQLModul.psm1 with a variable:

```
$logFile="C:\logfiles\SQLLog.txt".
```

I also have a manifest for this module: SQLModul.psd1 where I state: 
    VariablesToExport = '*'

When I Import this module: import-modul SQLModul all Functions but not this variable will be exported.
Thansk for your help.

Comment: Add `Export-ModuleMember -Variable logFile` to the bottom of `SQLModul.psm1`

Comment: Mathias, thanks, but still, having 30 variables should I add every single way that way?

Comment: If you _really_ want to export 30 module-scoped variables, yes! Although I have to ask _why_? I'm suspecting this may be [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - what exactly are you trying to _achieve_ by exporting 30 variables?

Comment: it was just a question, no one wants to export 30 variables, I just wander what is the clause in the manifest good for: VariablesToExport = '*', if I have to list all the variables by name in module?

Comment: Think of the exports in the `psd1` as a thin wrapper or dmz around the `psm1` - a module inside a module so to speak. The reason is that although it's rarely used, you can actually nest multiple dependent modules inside a single manifest, so the exports from a `psm1` and the `psd1` that references it is not always 1-to-1

Answer (score 0):

Think of the module manifest as a facade or proxy in front of the module(s) it load(s) - the manifest exporting `*` variables will only affect whatever variables were already exported from a nested `psm1` or managed module.

Place `Export-ModuleMember -Variable list,of,variable,names` at the bottom of your `psm1` file, in your case:

```
# define module functions, variables etc. 
# ...

Export-Module -Variable logfile
```

Placing `Export-ModuleMember -Variable *` in the `psm1` should also work, although that's probably a pretty bad idea, and is generally considered an anti-pattern